# Java Simple Project handling Resources

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have a simple java project and I have a class called Constants
where I store all my required paths in static variables, like this
for example:

```
public static final String PLAYFIELD_SMALL_IMAGE_PATH =  Constants.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Player_Small.png").getPath();
```

Works fine as long as I stay in my Eclipse ;)

but when I export my program to a JAR file and start it I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

it appears when I call the following for the first time:

```
Constants.PLAYFIELD_SMALL_IMAGE_PATH
```

If I start a second time I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFound: Could not initalize class Constants
```

What am I actually doing wrong?

EDIT 1:

I found this one here : ["NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401111/noclassdeffound-exception-could-not-initialize-class-error-help)

Seems to be exactly the same problem. So should I not use static variables?

EDIT 2:

If I use a static initializer block an ExceptionInInitializerError
is thrown instantly. without a static initializer block I was able 
to get to the first menu of my program.

EDIT 3:

Maybe another hint! When I extract my jar all graphics are directly in the root-folder so
i tried to use a relative path like this:

```
public static final String PLAYFIELD_SMALL_IMAGE_PATH = "Player_Small.png";
```

But if i do so my graphic isnt loaded.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the way you created the jar with eclipse

Comment: File -> Export -> Runnable JAR file -> Choose Main and Export-Path -> Finish

Comment: can you check jar tf <your jar file> | grep Constants ... and see if the file exist in the jar

Comment: cant use the grep command on windows but when i extract my jar the Constants class exists

Comment: @user2663778 `grep` exists for almost everything, including Windows. Although I'd use Cygwin anyway.

Comment: The "grep" command is either misspelled or could not be found.

Comment: If you have powershell under windows, then `grep` is spelled `Select-String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is exactly that:

```
public static final String PLAYFIELD_SMALL_IMAGE_PATH =  Constants.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Player_Small.png").getPath();
```

Read this article: [NoClassDefFoundError](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html). This Article explains how
to resolve your problem.

I would suggest you to take all your pathes out of your Constants class
into another class without using static varibles there.
And maybe use URL's instead of String-Pathes because as you mentioned
you use Images. Images will need URL's to be located because they 
arent on a HDD. If you dont use URL's your images may not be printed.

Answer (score 2):

First unpack your jar and check if all the classes are there.

You can do many things to resolve that issue, first I would recommend using maven and learn that (for starters check out [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)), but if you want to stay with minimal java project than you can try the following:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("File1.jpg");
```

That should help

Comment: im actually very familiar with maven but i wont use it for such small projects. and using Thread.currentThread()..... causes the same Error

Comment: Did you check your jar file if it contains 'Constants' class?

Comment: Yes it contains Constants.class

Comment: So how did you try it, with 'Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constants.File_name_blah_blah);'? Where is your file located? Maybe try to use absolute path for starters and see if that works?

Comment: I used Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(Constants.FileName).getPath(); my file is located under graphics/FileName and graphics is a resource folder of my project