# TomEE throws An invalid Lifecycle transition

Tags: java, maven, apache-tomee, multi-module, openejb

I'm doing a major refactor of a web application using the maven multi-module approach.
At the get-go there was only 1 module.
I've slowly been breaking out functionality and creating a dependency chain that the main module would depend on.

Other pertinent information worth mentioning:
We are using the following:

- TomEE (Apache TomEE-JAXRS 1.5.1)
- OpenEJB
- Apache Maven
- JDK 1.7.x

Currently my web-app is structured like this:

```
parent
  pom.xml  
     |
     common
       pom.xml
     |
     persistence
       pom.xml
     | 
     export
       pom.xml
     |
     main
       pom.xml
```

So...
The common module's pom has NO other module dependencies.

The persistence module's pom has the following dependencies:

```
common
```

The export module's pom has the following dependencies:

```
common
persistence
```

The main module's pom has the following dependencies:

```
common
persistence
export
```

The parent module's pom specifies the REACTOR Build Order as follows:

```
common
persistence
export
main
```

Prior to the creation of the `export` module everything would build and deploy fine; however, now that I've broken out additional stuff from main and put it into the export module, the build is fine, but when I deploy the generated WAR file, the following stack-trace shows up upon start-up:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1167)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1148)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:635)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1275)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:955)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:537)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Oct 05, 2016 12:51:23 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war    
StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]     org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed:
C:\java\servers\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.1\webapps\act-cde: Error building bean 'TaskDataAccessServices'.  Exception: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
Could not initialize class   com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices: Could not initialize class com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:959)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:537)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Error building bean 'TaskDataAccessServices'.  Exception: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
Could not initialize class  
com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices: Could not   
initialize class  
com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices
    at    org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EjbJarBuilder.build(EjbJarBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:713)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.load(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:425)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.loadClass(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.build(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EjbJarBuilder.build(EjbJarBuilder.java:66)
    ... 19 more
```

Notice the `TaskDataAccessServices` mentioned in the stack-trace.  This class is located in the `persistence` module.  What's weird is that it's NOT used at all in the `export` module, which I've just created.

Question of the day:  What's the best approach at debugging this issue?

I've thought about backing out changes one by one and putting classes back into the main module --- but this could take awhile ...

Wondering if there was a silver bullet approach to resolving this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `main` pom.xml file, I had the following `<dependency>`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In the `export` pom.xml file, I had the following `<dependency>`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.21</version>
 </dependency>
```

Little did I know that the `ehcache` had it's own dependency of `slf4j`.

Changing the `ehcache` `<dependency>` to the following fixed things up for me:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.3</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Figuring this out required me to back things out one at a time until things stopped breaking.

Lesson learned here:  commit small, commit often.

Answer (score 0):

I'd open up your artifact and see if `com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices` is actually present in it.

That's what this stack trace is telling you:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.myapp.cde.persistence.ejb.TaskDataAccessServices
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.load(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:425)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.loadClass(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EnterpriseBeanBuilder.build(EnterpriseBeanBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EjbJarBuilder.build(EjbJarBuilder.java:66)
    ... 19 more`

Comment: Unfortunately the TaskDataAccessServices.class file is present in the /WEB-INF/lib folder of the persistence JAR file in the exploded WAR. Good idea though...That would have been too easy!  : )

Comment: Awesome, that's a good first step. The problem is probably in the initialization of that class then... maybe try some of the things here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401111/noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-error Also make sure you're not running java8 bytecode in java7, etc